# How and can you increase the flow volume for a tub faucet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water

We recently built an addition onto our house of approximately a 1000 sq ft. The existing home had one or two prior additions to it  since the main part was built in 1930 something. The plumbing is the regular yellowish piping but for everything we added we used the newer pex piping.

In the new bathroom we have a stand up shower and a separate big soaking tub. My problem is the flow  or volume for the tub seems really low, like to the point that I gave up on the faucet and when my wife was ready to try out our new bathroom I pretty much filled the tub with a bucket line consisting of me and my four kiddos, haha...

Any helpful advice or something to try to increase the flow is very much appreciated.

Comment: So other faucets in the house have acceptable flow?

Comment: There was one existing bathroom and the kitchen sink and both are good...We also built like a laundry/mud room since the old laundry was very small and it was right next to the kitchen so it's now a pantry lol the hot water heater is also in the small old laundry room ... Hope some of that is useful for you

Comment: On the problem faucet: If you turn *just the cold* to full blast, then switch to *just the hot*, full blast, are the pressures seemingly equal, or does one or the other have considerably more pressure?

Comment: Something quick you can do is make sure the shut off valves are wide open for both the hot and cold feeds to the problem faucet. If one of them is partially closed...that may be the only problem.

Comment: What size pex was used. Is it possible the lines are pinched some place.

Comment: @user76471 "*We also built like a laundry/mud room*" **Like a laundry/mud room / or an actual laundry/mud room ?** I would like to buy some **punctuation please**, comma's and periods in the correct places would make digesting your words so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have a problem.  I am going to venture a guess that some debris got into the faucet on install. This can raise havoc with water delivery.  Can you disconnect the supplies going to the tub faucet and check the pressure at that point?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons why the cold water is not flowing. 
1-  As others have stated, there is a blockage in cold water to the faucet or at the cold water valve for the faucet
2-  If the faucet has an aerator, like mine, the aerator could be plugged with sediment